# Requests.get(zipfile) gets 'BadZipFile: File is not a zip file"

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, jupyter-notebook, zip, geopandas

I'm trying to load in shapefile that is in zipfile of the set of geo files. I've tried a couple of approaches and have been studying, and getting nowhere. The following code is supposed to work for Python 3.5.

I've tried Andrew Gaidus example approach and realize it is for prior Python version.  Oldja approach is from Python 3.x docs and should work. But problems keep coming up.

```
dls = "https://github.com/ItsMeLarry/Coursera_Capstone/raw/master/tl_2010_25 009_tract00.zip"
print('Downloading shapefile...')
r = requests.get(dls)
z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
print("Done")
z.extractall(path='tmp/') # extract to folder
filenames = [y for y in sorted(z.namelist()) for ending in ['dbf', 
'prj', 'shp', 'shx'] if y.endswith(ending)] 
print(filenames)
dbf, prj, shp, shx = [filename for filename in filenames]
print(shp)
lynnmap = gpd.read_file(shp)
```

I get 4 file names, like I should.  Now, at the lynnmap=gpd..., I get the error:

OSError: no such file or directory: 'tl_2010_25009_tract00.shp'.

Examples don't do an "open" operation, but I'm wondering whether geopandas is telling me that I should.

Comment: That's because the response is 404 Not Found (check `r.status_code`). Are you sure you have the correct URL?

Comment: @t.m.adam You are right.  I forgot that I need to use "raw" directory for download, not "blob".  Of course, this just leads me to the next mystery.  Did edit of the problem statement for that.  Thanks,

Comment: I think `shp` is just the file name and so `gpd.read_file()` fails to find the file because it is extracted in `tmp/`. You should use the absolute or relative file path, eg `tmp/tl_2010_25009_tract00.shp`.

Comment: t.m.adam OK, so append "tmp/" to all the file names.  I'll see what happens.  I wonder what would happen if I didn't extract it to a tmp folder.  I'll see.  The MACOSX and the Jupyter notebook have a contentious relationship re file management.  The disk behaves as if it has been partitioned with the Jupyter and the OS on separate sides blind to the other side.

Comment: I don't have much experience with Jupyter or MACs so I can't help with that. Generally it's best to use the absolute path of files, so they can be located even if they are not in the same path where the script is executed.

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is to just read the file from GitHub and create a GeoDataFrame from it (and you don't necessarily want to download and unzip it locally, for faster re-reading), you can read the file directly from the GitHub url using the `geopandas.read_file` function:

```
In [4]: df = geopandas.read_file("https://github.com/ItsMeLarry/Coursera_Capstone/raw/master/tl_2010_25009_tract00.zip") 

In [5]: df.head()                                                      
Out[5]: 
  STATEFP00 COUNTYFP00  ...    INTPTLON00                                           geometry
0        25        009  ...  -070.9744124  POLYGON ((-70.977153 42.452525, -70.9773139999...
1        25        009  ...  -070.9789107  POLYGON ((-70.986276 42.46005299999999, -70.98...
2        25        009  ...  -070.9853846  POLYGON ((-70.988809 42.460175, -70.9889149999...
3        25        009  ...  -070.9611517  POLYGON ((-70.95187 42.473647, -70.950974 42.4...
4        25        009  ...  -070.9925246  (POLYGON ((-71.000474 42.507547, -70.999544 42...

[5 rows x 13 columns]
```

The `geopandas.read_file` accepts a url, and can also handle a zip file of the different shapefile files automatically, and returns a GeoDataFrame.

Comment: The suggestions from t.m.adam worked well. And I am finally very pleased.  On to much else to do.  Are you saying that, with the geopandas, I could do a gpd.read_file directly from URL without unzipping? I need to use the shapefile to make a map and the prj file for reference for creating geodataframe. How does all that happen without an explicit unzip step?

Comment: @t.m.dama, It works as it's supposed to! Thanks. On to plotting map and making geopandas df to display data.  Its good to feel like I'm moving forward again.

Comment: The `geopandas.read_file` function does the unzipping (and loading of all different files, including the prj file) for you.

Comment: The goal is to create a geopandas dataframe.  I"m only showing part of the code as I proceed. You appear to be saying that the gpd.read_file creates the dataframe directly.  That means adding the reference info from prj and everything. Is my understanding correct?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is the purpose of the `geopandas.read_file` function: to create a GeoDataFrame from a file or set of files (and in this case, a zip of files). So in case of a Shapefile (or zip of the shp, prj, dbf, etc files), it handles the different files for you (reading both the geometries and attributes and the projection info).